# why Django redirect function returns to the same page

Tags: python, django, django-views

I have a website where there are different groups. As soon as you click on one of the groups, you are redirected to the details page of that group. This click happens via a post method, where the name of the group is sent to the server. There I check if it is a POST method, and since I use several on the page, I also check which one it is ['post-function']. Then the name of the group is stored in the session (this is important for a later function). Afterwards it should be redirected to the detail page. However, I always end up on the same page. In the console I can see that the details page is loading, but I am somehow redirected to the main page.

these are my URLS:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', index, name='home'),
    path('send', send, name='send'),
    path('datasheet/', datasheet, name='datasheet'),
    path('datasheet/intents/', intents, name='intents'),
]
```

datasheet is the page where all the groups are listed and can be clicked for the detail page

here are my views:

```
def datasheet(request):

    # error handling
    if 'error' not in request.session:
        error = "no_error"
    else:
        error = request.session['error']
        del request.session['error']

    # post methods
    if request.method == 'POST':


        # show group intents
        if request.POST['post-function'] == 'details-group':
            group_name = request.POST['showIntents']
            request.session['group'] = group_name
            print(request.session['group'])
            return redirect('/intents/')

    return render(request, './views/datasheet.html', {"error": error})

def intents(request):
    print("testing, if site opens")
    return render(request, './views/intents.html')
```

The output is:

```
[05/Oct/2022 12:26:48] "POST /datasheet/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[05/Oct/2022 12:26:48] "GET /datasheet/intents/ HTTP/1.1" 200 4832
[05/Oct/2022 12:26:48] "GET /datasheet/ HTTP/1.1" 200 3393
```

addition:
I think I have found the cause, but I don't know how to fix it. Below is my post call. I have reloaded the page there. Probably that's why I stay on this page. But if I remove this command now, nothing happens. The page is not reloaded and I am also not redirected.

```
let group_button = document.getElementsByClassName("groups-details");
    // for every Group there is a button to click --> show details
    for(let i = 0; i<group_button.length; i++){
        group_button[i].onclick = function(){
            if(group_button[i].type == "button"){

                show_intents = group_button[i].value
                let formData = new FormData();

                formData.append('post-function', "details-group");
                formData.append('showIntents', show_intents);
                formData.append('csrfmiddlewaretoken', token);
                fetch('/datasheet/', {
                    method: 'POST',
                    body: formData,
                }).then( () => {
                    window.location.reload();
                });
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Use the name of view so `return redirect("intents")`.

Comment: I am redirected but then redirected back again

Comment: But how is it possible, anyway use `return redirect("/datasheet/intents/")`

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not work. I think it has to do with the fact that this redirect is within a post request.

Comment: Place it just outisde the main POST method, so `# post methods
    if request.method == 'POST':


        # show group intents
        if request.POST['post-function'] == 'details-group':
            group_name = request.POST['showIntents']
            request.session['group'] = group_name
            print(request.session['group'])
        return redirect('intents')`.

Comment: i added my post call. I think thats the reason this doesnt work

Comment: Why is there a window.location.reload() at the end ? What do you mean by "nothing happens" ? you could return a JSONResponse with a URL, and use window.location.href to move.

Comment: it worked. @Benjamin_Mourgues Thank you. i didn't know why a server-side redirect is not enough, but must be set in the post call as well

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
return redirect('/datasheet/intents/')
```

OR:

```
return redirect('intents')
```

Comment: I already stated this in the above comments and the OP replied it doesn't work. Although, this is considered as [plagiarism](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plagiarism) but anyway ;)